# Unable to add RadSideDrawer functionality to Actionbar Navigation Button in Nativescript Angular

Tags: angular, nativescript

#### Nativescript 3.0.0 and Angular 4.0.0

So, let me first say that I've been following the [Getting Started](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/SideDrawer/getting-started) example and it's loading the sidedrawer onto my page as the tutorial intends.

My issue is trying to create a sidedrawer button in the action bar that opens the side drawer, instead of having that huge, ugly button do it. I somehow have to call the drawer within the navigation button, but give it the single functionality of opening the drawer. I don't know how though. Here is how I'm calling the action bar:

```
<ActionBar title="Feed" class="action-bar">
    <NavigationButton text="Navigation Drawer" (tap)="openDrawer()" class="navdrawer" android.systemIcon="ic_menu_moreoverflow"></NavigationButton>
    <my-drawer></my-drawer>
    <ActionItem text="Search" class="search-icon" (tap)="search()" android.systemIcon="ic_menu_search" ios.systemIcon="12" ios.position="right"></ActionItem>
</ActionBar>
```

Here is the rest of the code that pertains to the radsidedrawer setup, but it's mostly the same as the start up examples, just with a few naming changes.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core";
import { Page } from "ui/page";
import { ActionItem } from "ui/action-bar";
import { Observable } from "data/observable";
import { RadSideDrawerComponent, SideDrawerType } from "nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer/angular";
import { RadSideDrawer } from 'nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "my-drawer",
    templateUrl: "./drawer.html",
    styleUrls: ['drawer.css']
})
export class SideDrawerGettingStartedComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
    private _mainContentText: string;

    constructor(private _changeDetectionRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    }

    @ViewChild(RadSideDrawerComponent) public drawerComponent: RadSideDrawerComponent;
    private drawer: RadSideDrawer;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.drawer = this.drawerComponent.sideDrawer;
        this._changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.mainContentText = "SideDrawer for NativeScript can be easily setup in the HTML definition of your page by defining tkDrawerContent and tkMainContent. The component has a default transition and position and also exposes notifications related to changes in its state. Swipe from left to open side drawer.";
    }

    get mainContentText() {
        return this._mainContentText;
    }

    set mainContentText(value: string) {
        this._mainContentText = value;
    }

    public openDrawer() {
        console.log("Button works doe");
        this.drawer.showDrawer();
    }

    public onCloseDrawerTap() {
       this.drawer.closeDrawer();
    }
}
```

HTML file:

```
<RadSideDrawer tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton>
<StackLayout tkDrawerContent class="sideStackLayout">
    <StackLayout class="sideTitleStackLayout">
        <Label text="Navigation Menu"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout class="sideStackLayout">
        <Label text="Primary" class="sideLabel sideLightGrayLabel"></Label>
        <Label text="Social" class="sideLabel"></Label>
        <Label text="Promotions" class="sideLabel"></Label>
        <Label text="Labels" class="sideLabel sideLightGrayLabel"></Label>
        <Label text="Important" class="sideLabel"></Label>
        <Label text="Starred" class="sideLabel"></Label>
        <Label text="Sent Mail" class="sideLabel"></Label>
        <Label text="Drafts" class="sideLabel"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
    <Button text="Close Drawer" (tap)="onCloseDrawerTap()"></Button>
</StackLayout>
<StackLayout tkMainContent>
    <Label [text]="mainContentText" textWrap="true" class="drawerContentText"></Label>
    <Button text="OPEN DRAWER" (tap)="openDrawer()" class="drawerContentButton"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

CSS File:

```
button {
    font-size: 15;
    text-align: center;
}

.drawerContentText {
    font-size: 13;
    padding: 10;
}

.drawerContentButton {
    margin: 10;
    float: left;
}

.sideStackLayout {
    background-color: gray;
}

.sideTitleStackLayout {
    height: 56;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
}

.sideLabel {
    padding: 10;
}

.sideLightGrayLabel {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify which if the code is for the `<my-drawer></my-drawer>` is that a component that holds the RadSideDrawer. If yes that is incorrect as the RadSideDrawer should be placed as a single (root) child of the the HTML. http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/SideDrawer/getting-started

Comment: I have the code set up that it is indeed a component that holds RadSideDrawer. So you're saying that instead of having my main page with the RadSideDrawer component as an add on, I need to have the RadSideDrawer as the root and add on my other main page components to it?

Comment: Maybe yes, you can easily see if that is the issue by moving the RadSideDrawer to the main page. If that works that would be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I just ended up cutting and pasting the action bar code into the drawer html, making the drawer html more of an actionbar html. I feel like there's a better answer out there, but this definitely works well enough for me.